# The child of my <li> element disappears when I move it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The project I am working on has a submenu for large screens.  For small screens I need to move the submenu into the main menu which I do with the following `jQuery`.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".adminSubMenu").append($(".move"));
        } else {
            $(".sub-menu").append($(".move"));
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".adminSubMenu").append($(".move"));
        } else {
            $(".sub-menu").append($(".move"));
        }
    });
```

The code works if I use it to append to the `<ul>` list which has the class `adminSubMenu` in it.

```
<div id="navigate">
    <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
        <span class="sr-only">Mobile Menu Button</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse " id="navbar-main" style="height: 1px;">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm adminSubMenu">
               <li><a href="/rat/home.action">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="/rat/rule/ruleSummary.action">Rules</a></li>
               <li><a href="/rat/fiveYearReview/fiveYearSummary.action">5 Year Review</a></li>  
               <li><a href="/rat/admin/employee.action">Admin</a></li>  
                    <ul class="none"></ul>        
               <li><a href="/rat/logout.action" onclick="window.close();">Logout</a></li>                       
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</nav>
<div class="rowNav">
   <nav id="menu" role="navigation">
        <section id="subnav" >      
        <div class="rowNav">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse " id="navbar-sub" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav yamm sub-menu">
                    <li class="move"><a href="/rat/admin/refQuestion.action">Review Admin</a></li>                               
                    <li class="move"><a href="/rat/admin/employee.action">Employee Admin</a></li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div>     
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My problem is I want to move it into the `<ul>` which is marked with the class `none` in the code above.  When I removed the `adminSubMenu` class from the outer `<ul>` and put it in the inner `<ul>` in place of none I get two blank lines for my list.  The `<li>` elements are gone from the submenu but all that gets added to the sub `<ul>` is

```
<li class="move"></li>
<li class="move"></li>
```

When I put the code in Visual Studio to find my problem it worked.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking, but it seems like your current code is overkill for what you're trying to do. Why not just use Bootstrap classes to show/hide the menu based on screen size?

Comment: You have invalid html... A `ul` can not be a child of a `ul`.

Comment: @APAD1 Bootstrap will take a menu and collapse it into a hamburger menu using class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse " which we use.  But we have a submenu on this page and I couldn't find a way for bootstrap to take two separate menu lists and combine them into one hamburger menu.  I would prefer to do it with bootstrap if that was possible.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the tip.  I didn't look at the example I was following close enough.  I made the change and it appears to be working.  Thanks!